# iOS different output running in simulator and on device.Keyboard dot vs. comma

Tags: xcode4.4

i want put on keyboard (.) i run simulator it ok.
But i run iphone device, i seems (,)
my .m file ;
bText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;

please help me
(xcode 4.4.1 + ios 5.1 + iphone 3Gs)
![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue, might me a bug

```
NSRange rangeOfDash = [mediaTotal rangeOfString:@","];
```